# PostgreSQL json(b) - Convert string to array & update field

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql, sql-update, jsonb

I have a jsonb field in PostgreSQL with the following content:

`{ "object": { "urls": "A;B;C" } }`

What I want to do is **update** the value of `urls` inside the object and transform the string with semicolon separated values into a JSON array. So the result should look like this:

`{ "object" : { "urls": ["A", "B", "C"] } }`

I found out how to get a JSON array. Using

`to_json(string_to_array(replace((json->'object'->'urls')::text, '"',''), ';'));`

gives me `["A", "B", "C"]` (I think there should be a better way of doing it **without the conversion json -> text -> array -> json**. Suggestions are welcome)

But how do I update the `urls` field with the json array now? Probably I have to use `jsonb_set`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `jsonb` and the function [`jsonb_set()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html):

```
create table my_table(id int primary key, jdata jsonb);
insert into my_table values
(1, '{ "object": { "urls": "A;B;C" } }');

update my_table
set jdata = jsonb_set(
        jdata, 
        array['object', 'urls'], 
        to_jsonb(string_to_array(replace((jdata->'object'->'urls')::text, '"',''), ';'))
        )
returning *;

 id |                jdata                
----+-------------------------------------
  1 | {"object": {"urls": ["A", "B", "C"]}}
(1 row)
```

Comment: It worked well. I just had to add `WHERE jdata->'object'->'urls' IS NOT NULL`. Otherwise those rows had null as json (or jdata in your case).